# Authentication with Firebase and context API in react give me a warning. Is this the right approach?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to set up an authentication on my web application in React using firebase and Context API.
I am using Context API since as long as I understood I cannot save my jwt token in local storage in order to not be vulnerable to XSS attack and at the moment I do not want to use Redux.

in my App.js I have:

```
const {setUserInfo} = useContext(userInfoContext);
useEffect(() => {
  auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user) {
      setUserInfo({jwtToken: user.za});
    } else {
      setUserInfo({jwtToken: null});
    }
    console.log(user);
  });
}, [setUserInfo]);
```

The methos "auth.onAuthStateChanged" is triggered every time I logged in or I logged out using firebase.auth.

The compiler tell me that to eliminate the warning I should have "[setUserInfo]" instead of "[]". However, doing as he say, the method setUserInfo is executed twice. There is a better way to achieve the result without a warning?

Comment: I answered a similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66474451/firebase-auth-onauthstatechanged-looping-infinitely/66474888#66474888 

You can bring that `useEffect` inside your `ContextProvider` itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't clean up your effect when it is recomputed. As soon as you add `setUserInfo` to the dependency array, the effect is executed whenever its value changes. This means that you could potentially register many `auth.onAuthStateChanged` if the value of `setUserInfo` changes.

`auth.onAuthStateChanged` returns an unsubscribe function. You can simply return this function inside your effect, which will make react execute the unsubscribe function whenever the hook is executed again and prevent you from having multiple active listeners. I suggest you read more about this topic [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).